# iOS devices nginx redirect works in curl but not working in browsers (devices)

Tags: ios, iphone, curl, nginx

I'm trying to setup nginx to redirect different devices to different urls.
I have main domain and subdomain like https:// example.com and https:// m.example.com .
The idea is to redirect user on http request to corresponding https endpoints.
Desktop goes to https:// example.com
iPad goes to https:// example.com/ios
iPhone/iPod goes to https:// m.example.com/ios

My current config is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    location / {
        if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPad)') {
           return 302 https:// example.com/ios;
        }

        if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod|android)') {
            return 302 https:// m.example.com/ios;
        }

        return 302 https:// example.com$request_uri;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/letsencrypt/nginx-acme.conf;
}
```

When I test it with curl with different User-Agents I get right redirects. But browsers on devices open https:// example.com only.

Comment: Do you have the same rules on your `https` server? Could the browser be jumping to `https` directly (HSTS perhaps)?

Comment: No, I don't have same rules on https because iPad can navigate on all site. The idea is to redirect iPad only when user enters example.com in browser just how any people do casually. I tried Mobile Safari on devices and Device Emulation in Chrome Web Inspector.

Comment: And are you using HTTP Strict Transport Security on your `https` site?

Comment: Yes, seems like it's the problem. Thanks for pointing me in right direction.